# Clustered Map Icons w/o the markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm interested in using a feature "like" the clustering capabilities of google maps to show a count of items grouped by each US state.  What is a bit different than any example I've seen is that I dont actually want to have the individual markers just the counts - and when a user clicks on a count to open up a link.  Is the clustering api the way to go or just create custom markers?

Answer (score 0):

You can customise markers using [styledmarker library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/docs/examples.html). This library is used to create Markers that can be styled in different ways, such as changing the color or shape, or adding text labels. Below is an  example of how to use this library.

```
var styleMaker1 = new StyledMarker({styleIcon:new StyledIcon(StyledIconTypes.MARKER,{color:"00ff00",text:"A"}),position:myLatLng,map:map});
```

In your case `text:"A"` would be replaced with `text:count`

I have a [demo](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/test/viewmarkers.html) using this and a database of 2 tables state centroids and cities in usa. The marker shows the state and count of cities.